# How to implement fancybox in website (Beginners)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fancybox

For the life of me I can't seem to get Fancybox to work on my site. Any help would be much appreciated.
I even followed this guy's video and no dice:
 http://tutvid.com/webdesign/dreamweaver/how-to-use-fancybox-jquery-tutorial/

Here is my code that I was working with (I kept it really simple so I couldn't mess it up...didn't work...):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This better Work</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <!-- Fancybox JScript -->   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

        <div>
            <a class="fancybox" href="js/fancybox/images/1_b.jpg">
                <img src="js/fancybox/images/1_s.jpg" width="250" height="251" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <!-- Javascript Links -->

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/tk7fppte/)

Comment: @CerlinBoss The version I am using is v2.1.5

Comment: can you check the fiddle i have posted. Its working fine in that

Comment: is the "pop-up" happening? I'm not seeing it

Comment: Since the image URL is wrong it wont show any image. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/tk7fppte/1/)

Comment: Wow you're right! So, is my code weird then?

Comment: nope. For debugging check your developer console for any errors. i think the fancy box plugin is not included properly in your case.